# Get content of two fields above from csv file in python

Tags: python, csv

Within a file, I have rows. Within rows, I have fields. Here, I am searching for fields which contains only numbers. I need to print the content of field that is two fields above the current field. For instance,

```
with open("file1.csv", "rb") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
    for row in reader:
        for field in row:
            if field.isdigit():
                print two_fields_above_current_field
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean field[i] that you read 2 rows previously? You could read your rows into an array & then look back when you get a hit.

Comment: surely, this is a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work.

```
with open("file1.csv", "r") as f:
data = []
for i in f:
  data.append(i.split(','))
#or use csvreader..


for y in range(0,len(data)):
  for x in range(0,len(data[y])):
    if(y>=2 and data[y][x].isdigit()):
      print(data[y-2][x])
```